# Finding the transformation matrix given an object and how it's transformed

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a shape on a $2$ dimensional plane (axis are $x$ and $y$) and am told that the object stays the same with respect to the line $y=x$ and stretched by a factor of $2$ alone the line $y=-3x$. How would you find the transformation matrix for this object (or any point that follows these rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-3\end{bmatrix}$ as basis.
In this basis the transformation matrix is $T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$.

$BTB^{-1}$ is the corresponding transformation matrix in standard coordinates

Comment: I just want to double check my understanding. B comes from the 2 equations that I have y=x and y=-3x. And T comes from how the shape is transformed: column [1 0] for no change along y=x and column [0 2] for stretch by a factor of 2 along y=-3x

Comment: That's right. $B^{-1}$ translates standard coordinates to the new basis. In that new basis the transformation is simply a stretch by a factor of $2$ of the "$y$" coordinate, and this is done by the matrix $T$. After the transformation is done, the matrx $B$ translates from new basis to the standard coordinates.

Comment: As an example consider a vector $\dbinom{-5}{15}$ in standard coordinates. For this vector, the coordinates in the new basis is given by $B^{-1}\dbinom{-5}{15}$. In this new basis the vector transofrms to $TB^{-1}\dbinom{-5}{15}$. After this, we change back to the standard coordinates using $BTB^{-1}\dbinom{-5}{15}$

Answer (score 1):

You are after the linear map $f\colon\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2$ such that $f(1,1)=(1,1)$  and that $f(1,-3)=(2,-6)$. So,$$f(1,0)=f\left(\frac34(1,1)+\frac14(1,-3)\right)=\frac34(1,1)+\frac13(2,-6)=\left(\frac54,-\frac34\right).$$By a similar computation, you can get $f(0,1)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Where did the 3/4,1/4,And 1/3 coke from?

Comment: They cpme from solving the system $(1,0)=a(1,1)+b(1,-3)$.